# How to use str as list index in Python?

Tags: python

I read the name and the points of each person from a database and I need to have something like that:

```
myarray['Alex'] = 18
```

I've tried this :

```
myArray = []
cur.execute("SELECT name, point FROM mytable WHERE name <> '' ")

for row in cur.fetchall():
    name = row[0]
    myArray[name] = row[1]
```

but I got this error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: You want to use a dictionary for this, i.e. myArray = {}. Dictionaries can use strings as keys.

Comment: you can also try pandas to read data from mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), not an array:

```
myDict = {} # Here!
cur.execute("SELECT name, point FROM mytable WHERE name <> '' ")

for row in cur.fetchall():
    name = row[0]
    myDict[name] = row[1]
```